# Orion CB Error in <updateAction> DELETE

Tags: xml, fiware-orion

I need to delete an attribute of a entity but I obtain error "No context element found". I have applied the xml example of the tutorial ([Tutorial](https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_User_and_Programmers_Guide#Adding_and_removing_attributes_with_APPEND_and_DELETE_in_updateContext)).

The attribute that I want to delete is 'timestamp'. I have checked that this exits. Here I show the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<queryContextResponse>
<contextResponseList>
<contextElementResponse>
  <contextElement>
    <entityId type="Sensor" isPattern="false">
      <id>1</id>
    </entityId>
    <contextAttributeList>
      <contextAttribute>
        <name>timestamp</name>
        <type>string</type>
        <contextValue>2015-04-15 11:10:00</contextValue>
      </contextAttribute>
    </contextAttributeList>
  </contextElement>
  <statusCode>
    <code>200</code>
    <reasonPhrase>OK</reasonPhrase>
  </statusCode>
</contextElementResponse>
```

And here the xml code to delete it:

```
(curl localhost:1026/NGSI10/updateContext -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/xml' -d @- | xmllint --format - ) <<EOF
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<updateContextRequest>
<contextElementList>
<contextElement>
  <entityId type="Sensor" isPattern="false">
    <id>1</id>
  </entityId>
  <contextAttributeList>
    <contextAttribute>
      <name>timestamp</name>
      <type>string</type>
      <contextValue/>
    </contextAttribute>
  </contextAttributeList>
</contextElement>
</contextElementList>
<updateAction>DELETE</updateAction>
</updateContextRequest>
EOF
```

Could you help me?

Comment: Try one simple thing. Do a DELETE request like this with curl: `curl orion_host:1026/v1/contextEntities/1/attributes/timestamp -X DELETE `. If you get the same error, then maybe the entity does not exist really. If it works, then the problem may lie within the XML syntax.

Comment: But in this curl request, how I indicate the name of entity and the type?

Comment: It's in the URL. It states <entity> and <attribute> (I'm guessing that is what you mean by "type") like so: /v1/contextEntities/<entity>/attributes/<attribute>. In this case I substituted with your particular case entity=1 and attribute=timestamp.

Comment: How to indicate the id *and* type of an entity in the URL of a convenience operation is a very good candidate for a new separate question in SOF that I would be very happy to answer in the case somebody post it ;)

Comment: Yeah, maybe she meant "type" when she wrote "type".

Comment: I created two entities with type different (entityId type="Sensor" and entityId type="Node") and both with the same <id>1</id>. Maybe this is not correct but I didn't obtain any error when I made it. Then, if I use this DELETE request I don't know what entity will be deleted, Sensor or Node.

Comment: To solve it I can delete all entities and create them again as: ...<entityId type="Sensor"...<id>Sensor:1</id> and entityId type="Node" ...<id>Node:1</id>... This form is better? Another thing related with this. How I can see all entities that there are?

Comment: Responding new issues in comments use not being a good idea... things tend to mess. Thus, I'd recomment that you create 2 new questions in SOF: 1) one regarding your comment on May 6th 10:14 on how to delete one entity when you have both with same ID and different times, 2) one regarding your comment on May 6th 10:22 about how to see all the entities. Thanks!